# How absolute path can be changed dynamically?

Tags: php, apache, absolute-path, document-root

This is what we type for Absolute path:-

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Output is the following:-

```
C:/xampp/htdocs
```

Currently i am working in a folder naming "**project**", Therefore my project root is:-

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/project';
```

Output will be

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/project
```

Now if i upload my project to web-server with a folder name, say "**website**" i need to change the

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/project';
------------------------------------------
to
------------------------------------------
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/website';
------------------------------------------
or if i upload it in root then
------------------------------------------
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

I need to store files on different folders and directory levels.... so is there any way to make this thing dynamic any trick?

I want to minimize that hurdle and as renaming it all the time may can cause lot of time waste.

Once i used /project then /website and lastly directly to root... may be any trick through which we can bypass this hurdle and kind of declaration or stuff.. So that wherever we upload we just change a name in file and its done.... something like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize it in root dir with

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

This will not work as you expect if you use linked directory (original path will be used), which is a bummer in CodeIgniter for example

Comment: My question is once i used /project then /website and lastly directly to root... may be any trick through which we can bypass this hurdle and kind of declaration or stuff.. So that wherever we upload we just change a name in file and its done.... something like it

Comment: Well thats the hole point, you don't declare $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/project' or something like that any more, you use this project root instead, and don't have to edit it on any environment any more

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9189/discussion-between-abhilash-shukla-and-artjom-kurapov)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
$environments = array(
    'localhost' => 'development',
    'example.com' => 'production',
);

$active_environment = 'development';

foreach( $environments as $key => $value ){

    if( stristr( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $key ) ){
        $active_environment = $value;
        break;
    }
}

define( 'ENVIRONMENT', $active_environment );

    function getRoot(){

        switch( ENVIRONMENT ){
            case 'production' : return $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/website';
            case 'development' : 
            case default: return $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/project';

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the direction, i have edited my question a bit, please reconsider.... thanks

Comment: well, we use this approach for when project's life-cycle has it hosted on several machines - localhost, dev, qa, stage, production. All configuration settings are then based on the value of `ENVIRONMENT`. Now if you need only the directory the `dirname(__FILE__)` approach is the best.

Comment: but how to use `dirname(__FILE__)` ?